# Adding beans to Injection Context in Embedded Undertow/CDI/RestEasy

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, java-ee-7, weld, undertow

Given an embedded Undertow instance with CDI:

```
SomeObject myObject = new SomeObject();

UndertowJaxrsServer server = new UndertowJaxrsServer();
Undertow.Builder builder = Undertow.builder().addHttpListener(port, "0.0.0.0");
server.start(builder);

ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();
deployment.setApplication(new MyApplication(this));
deployment.setInjectorFactoryClass(CdiInjectorFactory.class.getName());

DeploymentInfo di = server.undertowDeployment(deployment, "/");

di.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader())
.setContextPath("/")
.setDeploymentName("My deployment")
.addListeners(Servlets.listener(org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.class));

server.deploy(di);
```

I would like to be able to inject things I've created outside of the container in the JAX-RS/CDI servlet context:

```
@Path
@Produces("application/json")
public class MyHandler {
  @Inject
  private SomeObject myObject;

  @Inject
  private UndertowJaxrsServer myServer;
}
```

How do I get arbitrary object instances into the CDI container?

Note: The use case is: I need to inject the class that the Undertow server instance is created in, inside of the CDI context. I cannot use JVM singletons, because I may need to spin up more than one.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this question?